# How to display incremented numbers in defaultContent in data table plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

Here is my code to where I want to get incremented numbers, because of indexed array(return values from API).

```
{ 
    "data": "",
    "defaultContent": "<img src='"+ imgStatusMap[orderDetails.orderItems[j].paymentStatus] +"' />
```

Here in place of `j`, I need to have dynamic incremented numbers.

```
var table = $('#orderitems').DataTable( { 
        "pagingType": "simple",
       //"pageLength": 1,
        "oLanguage": {
          "sInfo": "_START_-_END_ Of _TOTAL_",
          "sInfoEmpty": "0-0 Of 0",
          "oPaginate": {
              "sNext": '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
              "sPrevious": '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>'
            }
        },
       data: orderDetails.orderItems,

        "columns": [       
            { "data": "orderId" },
            { "data": "orderDate" },
            { "data": "noOfItems" },
            { "data": "","defaultContent": "<img src='"+ imgStatusMap[orderDetails.orderItems[j].paymentStatus] +"' /> "+orderDetails.orderItems[j].paymentStatus },
            {
                "className" :'details-control glyphicon-plus',
                "orderable" : false,
                "data"      :orderDetails.orderItems,
                "defaultContent": ''
            }],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
     });
```

Any one has any idea please help me out.

Comment: for loop or any if conditions wont work here. But I need to get values based on array index.

Comment: I found answer for this.

"aoColumnDefs": [
           {
                "aTargets": [1], //column number
                "mData": null, 
                "mRender": function (data, type, full) { //full has all data
  var  statusUpdate = "<img src='"+imgStatusMap[full.paymentStatus]+"' />";
                      return statusUpdate;
                    
                } 
            } 
         ],


Any html can be written here, including complex html's.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid (or at least it is in your question)